Expand $(1-z)^{-m}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ in powers of $z$
Expand $(1-z)^{-m}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ in powers of $z$

I've already read the links on this post and this post. The former concerns itself with the user's specific interest in a way to do it while the latter uses an approach that might lend itself to the approach I want to use. I'm mostly interested in solution verification. I may reference the second post.
To expand in powers of $z$, we observe that $f(z)=(1-z)^{-m}$ is analytic in neighborhoods about $z=0$ and hence has a Taylor expansion exists. We write $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(z)}{n!}z^n$. Now, we experiment with derivatives. We see that
$$f'(z)= -m(1-z)^{-m-1} \cdot (-1)  \hspace{0.2cm} ; \hspace{0.2cm} f''(z) = m(m+1)(1-z)^{-m-2}$$
$$\dots \hspace{0.2cm} f^{(n)}(z) = m(m+1)\dots(m+n-1)(1-z)^{-m-n}$$
$$ \implies f^{(n)}(z) =  \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!}(1-z)^{-m-n} $$
Evaluating at $z=0$ gives
$$f^{(n)}(0) = \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!}$$
Hence, the expansion reads
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!n!}z^n$$
$$\color{blue}{= \sum_{n=0}^\infty {m+n-1 \choose n}x^n}$$
In the posts I linked at the beginning, the answer was either derived via some binomial formula or via explicit manipulation of geometric series (in the style of the classic $\frac{1}{1-z}$ formula); the second post, which took advantage of the $\frac{1}{1-z}$ formula, did manage to interpret the coefficients using an "$n$ choose $k$" style but this style is different from my result. I just want to be sure that what I wrote is equivalent to the work of the two linked posts. It seemed most intuitive to me to simply do this directly a la $n^{th}$ derivatives - in this way, no fancy outside tricks are needed.

I think this is totally valid. In my calculus lectures, I derive the standard binomial formula (for $(1+x)^a$) this way from Taylor coefficients (of course that kind of glances over convergence issues, but you seem to be fine with that anyway). You can alternatively use that one and substitute $a=-m, z=-x$.

Ah, except that you forgot the inner derivative giving an extra $\cdot(-1)$ in each step. That removes the alternating factor $(-1)^n$ in your formula.

@TorstenSchoeneberg Oh, you're right! Thank you!

If you just want to have a rigorous derivation of the fact that $(1-x)^{-k}$ can be written as a power series for $|x|<1$, then you don't need to know Taylor's theorem, it suffices to know the sum of a geometric series, and that, within its radius of convergence, a power series is differentiable where its derivative given by the power series one obtains by naively differentiating the power series term-by-term:
For any $z \in \mathbb C$ we have $1-z^{n+1} =(1-z).\sum_{k=0}^n z^k$, and  thus since $\frac{|z|^{n+1}}{|1-z|}\to 0$ if and only if $|z|<1$, we have $(1-z)^{-1} = \sum_{k \geq 0} z^k$ if and only if $|z|<1$. It follows that this series has radius of convergence equal to $1$. Since any power series is differentiable within its radius of convergence with its derivative given by termwise differentiation, it follows that for all $z \in \mathbb C$ with $|z|<1$ we have
$$
(1-z)^{-2} = \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{(1-z)}\right)= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\sum_{j\geq 0} x^j\right) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty jz^{j-1} = \sum_{l=0}^\infty(l+1)z^l.
$$
Similarly, by induction we immediately obtain
$$
(k-1)!/(1-z)^{k} = \frac{\mathrm d^k}{\mathrm dz^k}\left(\frac{1}{(1-z)}\right)= \sum_{j=k}^\infty \frac{j!}{(j-k)!}z^{j-k} = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{(l+k-1)!}{l!}z^l
$$
and thus
$$
(1-z)^{-k} = \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \frac{(l+k-1)!}{(k-1)!l!} z^l = \sum_{l=0}^\infty \binom{l+k-1}{k-1} z^l
$$
Remark: The result about the derivative of a power series within its radius of convergence has a quick "two-variable" proof which goes as follows:
Claim: Let $f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R$, let $s_N(z) = \sum_{n=0}^N a_n z^n$ be the $N$-th partial sum of $f$, and let $g(z) = \lim_{N \to \infty} s_N'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty na_n z^{n-1}$ be the series obtained by termwise differentiation. Then $f$ is differentiable in $B(0,R)$ and $f'(z)=g(z)$.
Proof of claim: Note that if $|z|<r_1<R$, then as $r_1<R$ we have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|r_1^n<\infty$, and hence by comparison with this series it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n|a_n||z|^{n-1}<\infty$ for all $z \in B(0,R)$. Let
$$
g_n(z,w) = a_n\frac{z^n-w^n}{z-w} = a_n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^{n-k-1}w^k 
$$
and set $F(z,w) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(z,w)$. For any $r$, $0<r<R$, if $z,w \in \bar{B}(0,r)$ we have
$$
|g_n(z,w)| \leq \sum_{k=0}^n |a_n||z|^{n-k+1}|w|^k \leq n|a_n|r^{n-1},
$$
hence the Weierstrass $M$-test ensures that the $\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(z,w)$ converge uniformly on $\bar{B}(0,r)$ to a continuous function $F(z,w)$. Since $B(0,R)= \bigcup_{r<R} \bar{B}(0,r)$, it follows that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(z,w)$ converges absolutely (though not necessarily uniformly) on $B(0,R)$ to the continuous function $F(z,w)$.
But now for $z,w \in B(0,R)$ with $z \neq w$, $g_n(z,w) = a_n(\frac{z^n-w^n}{z-w})$ hence $F(z,w) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty g_n(z,w)$ is just $\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}$, while $g_n(z,z)=na_n z^{n-1}$ so that $F(z,z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty n.a_n z^{n-1}= g(z)$. Thus the continuity of $F(z,w)$ on $B(0,R)^2$ implies that $\lim_{z\to w}(f(z)-f(w))/(z-w) = F(w,w) = g(w)$ so that $f'(w) = g(w)$ as claimed.

I think that there is a mistake somewhere since
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n\,\binom{m+n-1}{n}\, z^n=(1+z)^{-m} \tag 1$$
but
$$(1-z)^{-m}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n\,\binom{-m}{n}\, z^n \tag 2$$

I see. I must admit that my understanding of the interpretation of ${-m \choose n}$ is quite limited (in particular, my confusion stems from the negativity of $m$), but whatever that interpretation may be, I suspect that there's a chance that the $(-1)^n$ and the negative $m$ in the binomial coefficient negate each other, hinting at Torsten's comment, unless I am mistaken

@GrigorHakobyan. Yes, you are correct. If I may suiggest, when you have a binomial term forget about combinatorics. Cheers :-)
